# I can't install the Azure Functions extension on VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Pretty much what it says on the tin.

I'm trying to download or otherwise add the Azure Functions extention for VS Code, and for some reason, I just can't. Has anyone else had this problem?

I've tried:

Searching for it in the extensions marketplace - it's like it doesn't exist

Trying to download it from the webpage version of the extensions marketplace - The install now link behaves like a dead link, and if I copy it to open in a new tab, it briefly throws an "Open in VS Code?" message, but then nothing happens.

Downloading it from the .vix file - VScode tells me that it's an unsupported action using the code template copied from microsofts own website.

Restarting the computer and trying all of these again. No joy. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm supposed to be writing a function app, and i'm slightly at my wits end because I can't advance without this particular little module.

Running VS code 2019 professional edition, all up to date, on a brand new lenovo thinkpad running windows 11 enterprise, also all up to date.

Comment: There's no `VS code 2019 professional edition`. I guess you mean `Visual Studio 2019`

Comment: For `Visual Studio` please have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs?tabs=in-process

Comment: I've tried uninstalling it currently, but its offering me Visual Studio 2019 Professional as my reinstall option? 

My problem isn't creating the functions project, it's downloading the functions extension to then work on the project